# Changing POST body of HttpServletRequest in Spring filter

Tags: java, spring, filter

I have a Spring filter:

```
  public class MyFilter implements Filter {

      public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                         FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

       }
  }
```

Now, if this request is a POST, I want to write/modify the POST body of the request before it hits my controller. Is there a way I can do this? I've looked around and could find plenty information on how to read the body, but not write

Comment: This is not possible, why do you want to change the request body?

Answer (score 0):

There is one more option but don't know whether it fits into your requirement.
Maybe it can help you out. The below approach is using Spring AspectJ.
Make changes in the below code according to your need.

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class WebServiceAPILoggingAspect {

    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(WebServiceAPILoggingAspect.class);

    @Before("execution(* com.progress.d2c.web.service.*.controller.*.*(..))")
    public Object controllerMethodsAdvice(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        Object proceedResponse = null;
        HttpServletRequest request = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
        String payload = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
        // Now write your code...
        try {
            proceedResponse = joinPoint.proceed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to complete the operation.");
            throw e;
        }
        return proceedResponse;
    }
}
```